# Using wavepackets instead of photons in quantum computer

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-optics, quantum-computer

Why does a photonic quantum computer require photons?  Why wouldn't wave packets work just as well, better in fact since it would get away from the use of fragile single photons? ([Article](http://news.sciencemag.org/sciencenow/2012/12/new-form-of-quantum-computation-.html))

Answer (score 1):

When using quantum optics for quantum computation, you can use also wave packets and not just single photons. There is a whole field of continuous-variable (CV) quantum computing that deals with this problem. There are both pros and cons to this approach compared to using single photons:

**Pros:**

- Entanglement in CV quantum optics can be generated deterministically using optical parametric amplifiers.
- Working with Gaussian wave packets is rather simple both in terms of theoretical description and experimental realization.

**Cons:**

- Gaussian states are not strictly orthogonal so that working with binary data will have a nonzero error rate.
- Computations with Gaussian states can be efficiently simulated using classical computers. This means that some non-Gaussian operation is required and these are usually quite demanding experimentally.